# Changed functions.php file and now site is blank

Tags: functions, wp-admin

I tried to change the functions.php CSS page, commenting out the original load fonts function and replacing it with my own. Now, when I try to access the site, I just get a blank page.

Even worse, when I try to go to the wp-admin, I also get a blank page.

I'm guessing that the load fonts function that I replaced with did not work, which is why I'm getting a blank page, but why can't I even access my wp-admin page? And how do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: There is likely an error in the code you replaced. Can you please post the new code you added.

Comment: WordPress doesn't always die gracefully, if there's an actual parse error, meaning the server can't read the code because of an error, you'll get that blank white page.

Comment: Without code, this question is impossible to answer, aside from: just restore the file as it was originally.

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your **question** to make answers possible.

Comment: Never dump any piece of code into your functions.php file on a live site. It is a huge pain in the butt if that piece of code make your site crash. Why not install something like xammp locally on your computer and test codes locally before uploading it to your live site. It will safe you tons of tears and heartbreak.

Answer (score 1):

A php error is causing the white page. Use FTP to replace the functions.php file with a fresh, unedited copy.

See [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) and [FTP Clients « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients) Or use your web host's file manager in your control panel.

Next time, keep copies of files and edit via FTP rather than the Wordpress theme editor.

Comment: +1 for "edit via FTP rather than the Wordpress theme editor". That thing is dangerous.